# link_to with :protocol isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a link use SSL. I'm using this code:

```
<%= link_to "Buy now!", line_items_path(:thing_id => @thing), :method => :post, :protocol => "https", :only_path => false %>
```

For some reason, the link is being generated with `http://` instead of `https://`.

I'm using Rails 3.0.3.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must put the :protocol option inside the path helper:

```
<%= link_to "Buy now!", line_items_url(:thing_id => @thing, :protocol => "https"), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, :only_path => false is necessary. It can only be omitted if :host is specified.

Comment: FYI, the real trick here is changing line_items_path to line_items_url because path helpers don't support :protocol

Comment: Additionally :only_path => false is worked for me.. thanks...:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [bartt-ssl_requirement](http://rubygems.org/gems/bartt-ssl_requirement) rubygem in your app, you can use the [ssl-url-helper](https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement#ssl-url-helper) to explicitly mention http or https protocol.

Advantages:

1. If you've disabled SSL check (in development environment), by following way: `SslRequirement.disable_ssl_check = true`, then passing `:secure => true` won't explicitly add https links to your view. This is not the case if you specify `:protocol => 'https'` and disable SSL check.
2. Also, its not necessary to change `line_items_path` to `line_items_url` at each place.