# Rails 3: button_to using https

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to link to a route using the https protocol.

I'm trying:

```
  <%= button_to '', carts_path(:service_id => @service),:only_path => false, :protocol => 'https://', :class => "buy-btn"%>
```

But it still goes to http://...

Comment: protocol is just "https" and not "https://"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered it seems, try this: [link_to with :protocol isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355967/link-to-with-protocol-isnt-working)